# Define field with macro, but Field cannot have type 'void' and/or Expected ')'

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

Trying to simplify writing boiler plate, but I get `Field cannot have type 'void'` and / or `Expected ')'`

Newbie c++, I've seen a bunch questions like this, but still can't figure it out. The errors are still too cryptic to me to able to google them..

```cpp
#define GAME_STAT(Stat) \
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Stats", ReplicatedUsing = OnRep_##Stat##) \
    FGameplayAttributeData ##Stat##; \
    GAME_STAT_ACCESS(UGameStats, ##Stat##); \
    UFUNCTION() \
    virtual void OnRep_##Stat##(const FGameplayAttributeData& Old##Stat##);
    
GAME_STAT("Health")
```

I want to generate the code with word "Health" instead of stand-in "Stat"

Thanks!

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: `GAME_STAT(Health)`?

Comment: Check what `#` and `##` mean for the preprocessor, you'll find your solution.

Comment: Also, please show the c++ code that you want this macro to generate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll look it up. As for what code I want to generate, it's the same as already posted with instead of saying Stat actually saying Health. Will also update this to question.

Comment: This won't work because the unreal header tool runs before the c++ pre processor.

Comment: @George thanks. Any way to actually do it?

Comment: There's not really anything directly equivalent. I think what you might be wanting to do is create a stat component that owns an array of stat data, maybe a struct containing the stat name and associated FGameplayAttributeData. If you want to inject unique behaviour for your OnRep function then you could create a UStatBase class instead and give it a virtual OnRep function (instead of an array of structs you would then have an array of UStatBase*).

Comment: @George thanks I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`##` is for pasting tokens together, but it looks like you think it is "reverse stringification".
It's also a binary operator, not an "around-ary" operator.

That is,

```
#define hello(x) Hello_##x
hello(World)
```

will produce

```
Hello_World
```

This should work (but is thoroughly untested):

```
#define GAME_STAT(Stat) \
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Stats", ReplicatedUsing = OnRep_##Stat) \
    FGameplayAttributeData Stat; \
    GAME_STAT_ACCESS(UGameStats, Stat); \
    UFUNCTION() \
    virtual void OnRep_##Stat(const FGameplayAttributeData& Old##Stat);
    
GAME_STAT(Health)
```

Comment: Thanks. Lemme just play with this a bit and I'll be back to mark accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for Unreal Engine - vars are declared correctly in source now, but not visible in engine >( but that's a different issue I guess so thanks for answering this! Cheers